# Sql Query aggregate result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following data

```
AgentID     AgentName   ReportDate  LOBName SubAct  CountA  CountB
------------------------------------------------------------------    
AgentSA1    Agent SA1   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA1     2   22
AgentSA1    Agent SA1   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA2     2   11
AgentSA1    Agent SA1   05/02/2020  SubActivity SA1     1    7
AgentSA2    Agent SA2   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA1     2    6
AgentSA2    Agent SA2   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA2     2    5
AgentSA2    Agent SA2   05/02/2020  SubActivity SA2     1    3
```

and I want result something like..

```
AgentID     AgentName   ReportDate  LOBName SubAct  CountA  CountB  CalculatedClo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AgentSA1    Agent SA1   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA1     2       22      4
AgentSA1    Agent SA1   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA2     2       11      4
AgentSA1    Agent SA1   05/02/2020  SubActivity SA1     1        7      1
AgentSA2    Agent SA2   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA1     2        6      4
AgentSA2    Agent SA2   04/30/2020  SubActivity SA2     2        5      4
AgentSA2    Agent SA2   05/02/2020  SubActivity SA2     1        3      1
```

Last column is the calculated one (`CalculatedClo`) which should have a calculation based on Group by Report Date and SubAct.

Can someone help me produce these values?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 and sample data is also better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: *should have a calculation* - and **what** is that calculation? If we don't know what you're trying to do and you're not telling us anything at all ....... how are we supposed to be able to help?

Comment: What is the calculation behind the results in column  `CalculatedClo`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to `sum` column `CountA` as a calculated column, you can simply use a `join` like the following:

```
;with temp as
(
    SELECT ReportDate, 
           SubAct, 
           SUM(CountA) Summed
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ReportDate, 
             SubAct
)
SELECT t.*, x.Summed as CalculatedCol
FROM YourTable t
JOIN temp x ON t.SubAct = x.SubAct AND t.ReportDate = x.ReportDate
order by AgentID, ReportDate;
```

Please find the demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=046a44ea55bdee6bde1006298036ec3f)**.